# PHP Sessions don't persist after page reload

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I have an EC2 instance running my application, but for some reason the session disappears when I reload the page.

This is my index.php file:

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['test'] = 'asdsadasdasd';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION);
```

I open that, and the I open this test.php file:

```
<?php
session_start();

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION);
```

The session array is always empty, I can see the session files being created on the server though.
Can anyone point me to a direction?

Comment: Have you tried a different browser to rule out client side issues, I just mention it because it's very easy to do and will help narrow down the possible issues.

Comment: Make sure your browser is accepting cookies.

Comment: @BGomez as per Vlam suggestion, you can open browser console then check for cookies (Firefox: Storage tab > Cookies; Chrome: Application tab > Storage > Cookies).